Analytical solution to a system of equations with exponentials relating to dry heat sterilization
For my job, I sometimes deal with lethality values for units equipped with dry heat sterilization cycles. We run one of these cycles and obtain temperature readings at a given location within the unit across several time points so at a given location we have temperatures $\textbf{T} = [T_1, T_2, ... T_N]$ where $N$ is the number of timepoints in the study. The total lethality at a location is then given by $$L_K = \sum_{i=1}^{N} 10^\frac{T_i-K}{z}$$ where $K$ is a given base temperature for the study (often between $160^{\circ}$C and $180^{\circ}$C) and $z$ is a coefficient related to the microorganism being killed. When this is unknown its assumed to be $20^{\circ}$C.
My question relates to converting between different values of $K$. For example, say I have determined that for a given study I have $L_{180^{\circ}C} = 100$ and I want to know $L_{170^{\circ}C}$ without knowing each individual temperature. I tried for a while to solve this analytically, but I couldn't figure it out. I wrote some code which generated many 60 minute 'sterilization cycles', found the lethalities at different values of $K$ and ran a linear regression between these lethalities to obtain their conversion coefficient. Here's the code:
lowtemp <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 10000)
hightemp <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 10000)
conv <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 101)
for (i in 100:200){
   for(j in 1:10000){
    temps=rnorm(60,180,1)
    leth1 <- sum(10**((temps-i)/20))
    leth2 <- sum(10**((temps-180)/20))
    lowtemp[j] <- leth1
    hightemp[j] <- leth2
}
model <- lm(lowtemp ~ hightemp)
conv[i] <- model$coefficients[2]
}

After looking at all the corresponding model coefficients I could see that the formula appears to be $L_{K_2} = L_{K_1}\times 10^\frac{K_1-K_2}{z}$
If anyone can provide insight on how you might solve for the unknown $L_{K}$ analytically or, if its not possible analytically, how such a simple looking solution arises, that would be awesome. Thanks.

It's just the law of exponentials $a^{b+c} = a^b a^c$ and the distributive law.  So
$$\eqalign{L_K &= \sum_{i=1}^N 10^{(T_i - K)/z} \cr
    &= \sum_{i=1}^N 10^{T_i/z} 10^{-K/z}\cr &= 10^{-K/z} \sum_{i=1}^N 10^{T_i/z}}$$
and then indeed
$$ L_{K_2} = L_{K_1} 10^{(K_1 - K_2)/z} $$
